# Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in C#?

Tags: c#

edittted:

**I already debug, I figure out that once I fill all the fields, autmatically generate a new row empty, and once it is stored in the dabase, it follow with the loop foreach, and automaticaly detect null reference this is an image, I hope you understand me img8.imageshack.us/i/error3xh.jpg**

I need your help, I can't control the exception,here is my method and the error say System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object", how can I fix it, control the exeption, no more messages of this type?, no matter how its the structure : the error is the line ** if (combo3 == null || combo4 == null) **

[image]

```
private void btnCronograma_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string connstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\amaury\\Documents\\TEC\\Septimo Semestre\\Administracion de proyectos de ingenieria de softwaere\\nuevo4\\nuevo\\Office\\Office\\Policias.accdb";
  using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstring))
   {
    conn.Open();

    string sql = "INSERT INTO IndicadorProyecto (idProyecto, idMes, meta, real) VALUES(@idProyecto , @idMes , @meta, @real)";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);

  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView8.Rows)
  {
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell combo3 = row.Cells["idProyecto"] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell combo4 = row.Cells["idMes"] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;

    if (combo3 == null || combo4 == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No se pudo convertir");
        continue;
    }

  int idProyecto = int.Parse(combo3.Value.ToString());
  int idMes = int.Parse(combo4.Value.ToString());
  int meta = int.Parse(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
  int real = int.Parse(row.Cells[4].Value.ToString());  

  cmd.Parameters.Clear();
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idProyecto", idProyecto);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idMes", idMes);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@meta", meta);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@real", real);


  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
}
```

this is the complete error

> Consulte el final de este mensaje para
>   obtener más detalles sobre cómo
>   invocar a la depuración  Just-In-Time
>   (JIT) en lugar de a este cuadro de
>   diálogo.
>
> ************** Texto de la excepción ************** System.NullReferenceException:
>   Referencia a objeto no establecida
>   como instancia de un objeto.    en
>   Office.Form1.btnCronograma_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) en
>   C:\Users\amaury\Documents\TEC\Septimo
>   Semestre\Administracion de proyectos
>   de ingenieria de
>   softwaere\nuevo4\nuevo\Office\Office\Form1.cs:línea
>   726    en
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs
>   e)    en
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs
>   e)    en
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs
>   mevent)    en
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&
>   m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks) 
>   en
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    en
>   System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    en
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    en
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&
>   m)    en
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    en
>   System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr
>   lparam)

Comment: Which line gives the error? I'm guessing one of the `int.Parse` lines.

Comment: the error is in the line if (combo3 == null || combo4 == null)

Comment: I delete that line and the erros say is in foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView8.Rows) , I dont know

Comment: Try capturing the error as text instead of a screenshot.

Comment: @peggalvan can you tell us in which line the exception is been thrown? you exception message says line 726 but we can't tell which is that one, and there is no way 'if (combo3 == null || combo4 == null)' can cause an exception.

Comment: foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView8.Rows) this causes the error

Comment: -1 This kind of exception is easy to find. It occurs when, and only when, there is an operation of `some_expr_evaluating_to_null.Member`. Simply inspect the line and find out which expression(s) that have members invoked upon then may evaluate to null. Using a debugger really helps.

Comment: I already debug, I figure out that once I fill all the fields, autmatically generate a new row empty, and once it is stored in the dabase, it follow with the loop foreach, and automaticaly detect null reference this is an image, I hope you understand me http://img8.imageshack.us/i/error3xh.jpg/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think most likely cause is that `row.Cells[3].Value` or `row.Cells[4].Value` are null (since you have not given them a value) and `.ToString()` throws a null exception.

Change the code to:

```
int meta = int.Parse(row.Cells[3].Value == null ? "0" : row.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
int real = int.Parse(row.Cells[4].Value == null ? "0" : row.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Did you mean to use break; instead of continue; ? What is the dataGridView8? Does it have value? What about dataGridView8.Rows? Add MessageBox.Show(dataGridView8.ToString()) anf MessageBox.Show(dataGridView8.Rows.Count.ToString())

Comment: no I simply delete that line but now the error is in foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView8.Rows), the datagridview8 is in my image, It doesn have a value, an the message box is just for seeing that is taking the correct values

Comment: depending on the .net version you can now use the null-coalescing operator `??` like this: `int.Parse(row.Cells[x].Value?.ToString() ?? "0")`, which is imo easier to read. See the  [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) for more info

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark, but the header row is one of the rows in the collection.  Try adding

```
if(row.index != 0)
```

just inside the `foreach`.  I can't remember, but the index might be -1.

Comment: I already debug, I figure out that once I fill all the fields, autmatically generate a new row empty, and once it is stored in the dabase, it follow with the loop foreach, and automaticaly detect null reference this is an image, I hope you understand me img8.imageshack.us/i/error3xh.jpg

Answer (score 0):

How to debug:

When you run the application in DEBUG mode (F5 in Visual Studio) and the exception is thrown, Visual Studio will stop and highlight a line in yellow. Here the exception was thrown. Place a breakpoint at this line, restart the application and when it stops at the breakpoint, observe what is null by hovering mouse over the line.

Line `if (combo3 == null || combo4 == null)` cannot throw NullReferenceException. I guess you were running an old version of the .exe, so it reports old line numbers.

From your code it seems that either `row.Cells[3].Value` or `combo3.Value` is null. Hint: you can never have a null value before dot '`.`'.

Comment: I already debug, and row.cell[3].value and combo3.value are null when the lopp foreach arrive in the empty space that it is generated once the user choose something from the combobox, but how can I fix this, I tried but nothing happens HELP!!

Comment: int idProyecto = int.Parse(combo3.Value.ToString() == null ? "0": combo3.Value.ToString());
                int idMes = int.Parse(combo4.Value.ToString() == null ? "0" : combo4.Value.ToString());
                  
                 


                
                int meta = int.Parse(row.Cells[3].Value == null ? "0" : row.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
            int real = int.Parse(row.Cells[4].Value == null ? "0" : row.Cells[4].Value.ToString());